# PHP SOAP call leaving an open resource

Tags: php, soap, resources

In PHP, I have a situation where I have to do thousands of SOAP calls in one execution, and from time to time, I reach the max number of opened files. I don't want to change the ulimit of the server as the problem will still occur later when I have more calls to do. And I can't change the logic of the thousands of calls made.
After some debuging, I found out that the SoapClient creates (and leaves open) one resource for each call.

Here is a testing script:

```
namespace MyTest;

use SoapClient;

echo "Open resources before new SoapClient: " . count(get_resources()) . "\n";
$soapClientArray['keep_alive'] = false;
$soapClient = new SoapClient('https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL', $soapClientArray);
echo "Open resources after new SoapClient: " . count(get_resources()) . "\n\n";

echo "Open resources before soapCall: " . count(get_resources()) . "\n";
$resultCall = $soapClient->__soapCall("CelsiusToFahrenheit", ['Celsius' => '25']);
echo "Open resources after soapCall: " . count(get_resources()) . "\n\n";
var_dump($soapClient);

echo "Open resources before soapCall: " . count(get_resources()) . "\n";
$resultCall = $soapClient->__soapCall("FahrenheitToCelsius", ['Fahrenheit' => '25']);
echo "Open resources after soapCall: " . count(get_resources()) . "\n\n";
var_dump($soapClient);

unset($soapClient);
echo "Open resources after unset: " . count(get_resources()) . "\n\n";

var_dump(get_resources());
```

The output being:

```
Open resources before new SoapClient: 0
Open resources after new SoapClient: 2

Open resources before soapCall: 2
Open resources after soapCall: 4

D:\www\TESTS\soap2.php:17:
object(SoapClient)[1]
  public '_stream_context' => resource(2, stream-context)
  public '_keep_alive' => int 0
  public '_soap_version' => int 1
  public 'sdl' => resource(3, SOAP SDL)
  public 'httpurl' => resource(7, SOAP URL)

Open resources before soapCall: 4
Open resources after soapCall: 6

D:\www\TESTS\soap2.php:22:
object(SoapClient)[1]
  public '_stream_context' => resource(2, stream-context)
  public '_keep_alive' => int 0
  public '_soap_version' => int 1
  public 'sdl' => resource(3, SOAP SDL)
  public 'httpurl' => resource(11, SOAP URL)

Open resources after unset: 4

D:\www\TESTS\soap2.php:27:
array (size=4)
  5 => resource(5, SOAP URL)
  7 => resource(7, SOAP URL)
  9 => resource(9, SOAP URL)
  11 => resource(11, SOAP URL)
```

The `var_dump()` after each call shows a `public 'httpurl' => resource(7, SOAP URL)` that is changed after each call. A call to `is_resource()` on that resource returns `true` which means it is still open (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-resource.php `it will return false if value is a resource variable that has been closed`)
I tried to unset the soapClient after each call to re-instantiate one but those httpurl stay open.
I tried to set a `connection_timeout` to 1 with a `sleep(2)` between each call but those httpurl stay open.
The httpurl property is not documented (apart from its declaration).
The resource type "SOAP URL" is not documented in https://www.php.net/manual/en/resource.php

Does anyone know how the `httpurl` can be closed?

Comment: Seems like there is a [bug reported](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=81029) on this issue, a couple of years ago now.

Comment: Thanks, but I specifically set the keep_alive option to false, and the issue is still here. But it may be somehow related (but don't know how)

Comment: You say that you « can't change the logic of the thousands of calls made« . But couldn’t you make an html page with some javascript that does one ajax or fetch call for each resource? If speed is not an issue, this technique helped me from time to time.